# Does TypeScript reconciliate the intersection of a sparse array type and non-sparse array type?

Tags: typescript, typing

## Problem Statement

The TypeScript 4.8 static type inference/check seems to be inconsistent:

```
type A = number[] & (number|undefined)[];
type B = (number|undefined)[] & number[];

function arrayAccess_A(a: A) { return a[0]; }  // returns a 'number'
function arrayAccess_B(b: B) { return b[0]; }  // returns a 'number'

function mapFirst_A(a: A) { return a.map(it => it)[0]; }  // returns a 'number'
function mapFirst_B(b: B) { return b.map(it => it)[0]; }  // returns a 'number | undefined'
```

I find it odd that one of the methods gives a different return type, what is the reason?

## Previous question text (obsolete)

*(You may stop reading here, what follows is the content from my original post, after some feedback from [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) I felt that it was not very clear.)*

I try to declare that a sometimes sparse array field `{ data: (number|undefined)[] }` of some type `WithSparseData` is now not sparse, using type intersection `WithSparseData & { data: number[]`.

```js
// type with a sparse array field
type WithSparseData = {
  data: (number | undefined)[];
  moreData: any;
};

// two ways trying to express that the array field is no longer sparse
type WithContiguousData_A = { data: number[] } & WithSparseData;
type WithContiguousData_B =                    WithSparseData & { data: number[] };

// rightfully rejected by the static type checker
const assignFirstToNotNull_1 = ( numbers: WithSparseData ): { first: number } => ({ first: numbers.data[0] });
const mapAllToDouble_1       = ( numbers: WithSparseData ) => ({...numbers, data: numbers.data.map(it => 2*it) });

// accepted by the static type checker
const assignFirstToNotNull_A = ( numbers: WithContiguousData_A ): { first: number } => ({ first: numbers.data[0] });
const assignFirstToNotNull_B = ( numbers: WithContiguousData_B ): { first: number } => ({ first: numbers.data[0] });

// also accepted by the static type checker
const mapAllToDouble_A       = ( numbers: WithContiguousData_A ) => ({...numbers, data: numbers.data.map(it => 2*it) });

// rejected by the static type checker !!!
const mapAllToDouble_B       = ( numbers: WithContiguousData_B ) => ({...numbers, data: numbers.data.map(it => 2*it) });
                                                                       // 'it' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048) ^^
```

**In particular**, the type of `it` in line 23 is inferred to be `undefined | number`, whereas the `first` in line 17 is inferred to be `number`; although both are computed from `WithContiguousData_B`, the inferred type differs.

Questions:

- is this a bug of the static type checker?
- should the order `{ data: number[] } & WithSparseData` versus `WithSparseData & { data: number[] }` matter ? is this specified, or may future TypeScript compilers change behavior?

Comment: It's essentially a design limitation of TS; see [ms/TS#41874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41874).  Intersections of types with same-named methods behave like those methods are *overloads* and therefore order-dependent, so intersections of arrays are best avoided.  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up a full answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your comment! I updated the post with line numbers: in line 17 and 23, I expected the types of "first" resp. "it" to be the same, but they are not.

Comment: Did you understand my first comment?  Intersections of functions/methods are seen as [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with multiple call signatures, and such call signatures get resolved in order.  One of those orders will end up calling `map()` on `number[]`, and the other will end up calling `map` on `(number | undefined)[]`.  Arrays do not compose well via intersection, as laid out in ms/TS#41874.

Comment: I'm happy to write up a full answer post that explains this in detail, as long as you agree that it addresses your question.  If you do not agree: what, specifically, am I missing?

Comment: I guess I'm going to go ahead and write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz I have shortened the minimal example to six lines, at the top. It seems [ms/TS#41847](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41874) is about intersecting `string & number`, with no intersection overlap, whereas I wonder about the TypeScript result of `number & (number | undefined)`. Also, assuming `A & B ≠ B & A`, then the 6-line-example should return 2 vs 2 instead of 3 vs 1 different return types, right? Thank you for giving it some thought!

Comment: The [relevant comment by the TS team dev lead](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41874#issuecomment-742743839) does not depend on whether you are intersecting `string` and `number` vs `number` and `number | undefined`.  Intersections of *function types* are order dependent, but intersections of non-functions are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have seen, [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of [array types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-array-type) do not behave as most people would expect them to. This is effectively a limitation of TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#41874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41874) for an authoritative answer.

---

**Intersections of non-function types are generally not order-dependent**

This is the behavior most people expect from intersections, where `X & Y` is equivalent to `Y & X`.  For example, when you index into an intersection of arrays with a `number` key, you get the order-independent intersection behavior you probably expect.  Let's use your `A` and `B` types

```
type A = number[] & (number | undefined)[];
type B = (number | undefined)[] & number[];
```

and see what you get when you index into them with a numeric key:

```
type ANumber = A[number];
// type ANumber = number

type BNumber = B[number];
// type BNumber = number
```

An array type `Array<T>` has a numeric [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) whose property type is `T`.  Thus `Array<number>[number]` is `number`, while `Array<number | undefined>[number]` is `number | undefined`.  And for both `A` and `B`, the numeric index signature gives you the intersection of those: `(number) & (number | undefined)` or `(number | undefined) & (number)`, which is `number` in both cases.

That's responsible for the behavior of the `arrayAccess_` functions:

```
function arrayAccess_A(a: A) { return a[0]; }  // returns a 'number'
function arrayAccess_B(b: B) { return b[0]; }  // returns a 'number'
```

That all makes sense, I hope.

---

**Intersections of function types are generally order-dependent**

On the other hand, TypeScript treats an intersection of *function types* as a single [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) function with multiple call signatures.  And overloaded function behavior can depend on the order of the call signatures, since they are resolved in order.  Contrast the behavior of the following overloaded functions:

```
declare function foo(x: string): number;
declare function foo(x: string): string;

const fooResult = foo("abc"); // number (not string)
fooResult.toFixed();

declare function bar(x: string): string;
declare function bar(x: string): number;

const barResult = bar("abc"); // string (not number)
barResult.toUpperCase();
```

Both `foo()` and `bar()` have two call signatures which accept a `string`, where one call signature returns a `string` and the other returns a `number`.  When you call `foo()`, the compiler resolves the call with the `number`-returning signature, because it comes first.  But when you call `bar()`, the compiler resolves the call with the `string`-returning signature, because it comes first.

For overloads this order-dependence probably seems natural, but it might be surprising to see the same behavior with intersections of functions:

```
declare const foo: ((x: string) => number) & ((x: string) => string);

const fooResult = foo("abc"); // number (not string)
fooResult.toFixed();

declare const bar: ((x: string) => string) & ((x: string) => number);

const barResult = bar("abc"); // string (not number)
barResult.toUpperCase();
```

As you can see, an intersection of functions behaves identically to the equivalent overload.

So now let's look at the `map` method of your `A` and `B` types in turn:

```
type AMap = A['map'];
/* type AMap = (
     <U>(cb: (val: number, idx: number, arr: number[]) => U, ths?: any) => U[]
   ) & (
     <U>(cb: (val: number | undefined, idx: number, arr: (number | undefined)[]) => U, 
       ths?: any) => U[]
   ) 
*/

type BMap = B['map'];
/* type BMap = (
     <U>(cb: (val: number | undefined, idx: number, arr: (number | undefined)[]) => U, 
       ths?: any) => U[]
   ) & (
     <U>(cb: (val: number, idx: number, arr: number[]) => U, ths?: any) => U[]
   ) 
*/
```

So for the `A` type, the `map` method is an intersection of function types where the first call signature's callback accepts a `number` value, while in the `B` type, the `map` method is an intersection of function types where the first call signature's callback accepts a `number | undefined` value.

And that is directly responsible for the following behavior:

```
function mapFirst_A(a: A) { return a.map(it => it)[0]; }  // returns a 'number'
function mapFirst_B(b: B) { return b.map(it => it)[0]; }  // returns a 'number | undefined'
```

So that's why it happens.  Intersections of functions acting like overloads is often desirable.  To be clear, nobody *likes* how this happens when you intersect array types, but according to [the comment by the TS team dev lead](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41874#issuecomment-742743839), it's the best they can do (paraphased slightly):

> Array intersection is weird since there are many invariants of arrays and many invariants of intersections that can't be simultaneously met. For example, if it's valid to call `x.push(z)` when `x` is `X`, then it should be valid to write `xy.push(z)` when `xy` is `X & Y`, but that creates an unsound read on `(X & Y)[number]`.
>
> In higher-order the current behavior is really the best we can do; in zero-order it's really preferable to just write `Array<X & Y>`, `Array<X> | Array<Y>`, or `Array<X | Y>` depending on which you mean to happen.

They suggest that instead of using intersections of array types, you use something else that more closely represents your intent. How do do that is beyond the scope of this question, though.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=false&ts=4.9.4#code/LAKAdghgtgpgzgBwgYxgAgGIFczIC4CWA9mAMp4R4yxh5xoDeoaaAJjMgDYQBO6AZjnzEwafkSIAKAB4AuNHDw8CYAOYBKeWCxQARjB4BuZmw7c+YoYRJiJM+YuVrNCpStXGQJ5CUW2iAErwWJx4aAC8-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-PcD2PV1TxZc8ZjQKAIAQWoeEUUdx0nV8d0-CAKmghBJAIQ4SRwws1w3Ld0lQoCjxPM8uhsTC4IQh8nzQF9GAA3cegwmDsNwtB8O-Ij-1I+hgJbascxgPMwAaMCw0jdBowAWRg7lowTQ9MMPddQBSAAqNAS1khSEArEwWDQAAeD4iUkZAGMkAA3CBOGWYUABpuNYA0W1c7snNWZN6RJD5XLwAALOAAH55AgMBw38tAPmTYyKWpSRjJYczLOs3F7Mck1sizUTxIaVyCHcnyDC8q9cWE-LazE+tG1iwK0FSkyQvCyLosahKnjQClQC0lJpLLAzuVLFS1I0kBtN0mTGJGyIUp6tKLKsmzsrKkUarrCTWGK0rcp4Cr1RudMtrqnaGu1JqWpYNqIv3Tqru6kykpyFr0tWrKHI2vaPNdI6Nr8q6gtC+6opip6k0S5qQAG9Y9JjAA5dNImUltJsFBHo2RqtIhbIb0FLHHVlGhN0c8THZqJlGDqAA)

Comment: Wow, thanks for that answer! I think I got it when you wrote `A['map']` where I was expecting `A.map` (like an extension function, where `typeof(A)` is evaluated before `typeof(map<A>)`); now it starts to make sense!